# console.logが出力されないことがある

Tags: monaca, cordova

MonacaクラウドでiPhone向けのアプリを試作中です。
以下のコードをiPhoneのmonacaデバッガで実行しても、success、errorいずれもApp Logに表示されません。alertのコメントを外してalertを出すとApp Logも表示されます。

以前からApp Logに出るべきものが出ておらずコードの追跡が困難なことがあり、不安定なのかと思っていましたが、今回はっきり再現するパターンが作れたと思います。

私の無知大ボケなのかもしれず戦々恐々なのですが、困っておりお叱りも覚悟の上質問いたします。
何かおわかりになりましたら、宜しくお願いいたします。

iPhone5/iOS8.1.3、Monaca Debugger4.0.0、Cordova 4.1.0 Platform 3.7.0

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- user -->
    <script>
        "use strict";
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
            });
        
        function onDeviceReady(){
            console.log('start');

            navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles){
                //alert('success');
                console.log('success');
            }, function(){
                //alert('error');
                console.log('error');
            }, {limit: 1, duration: 120});
        }
    </script>
    <!-- user -->

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2015/05/01 9時追記
試したところ以下のコードではsuccess、error共に2、3は実行され、1は出ませんでした。

```js
function onDeviceReady(){
  console.log('start');

  navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles){
    console.log('success');
    alert('success2');
    console.log('success3');
  }, function(){
    console.log('error');
    alert('error2');
    console.log('error3');
  }, {limit: 1, duration: 120});
}
```

2015/05/01 10時追記
他のコールバックではどうかと思いsetTimeoutを試しましたが問題ありませんでした。

しかし、以下のコードのようにsetTimeoutとcaptureVideoを同時に実装した時、Timeoutが発生した時にVideoが終了していた場合はlogにtimeout1,3が出力されましたが、Video実行中の時は出力されませんでした。

このことからcaptureVideo実行中あるいはその直後はconsole.logが出力されないということかな、と想像します。
仕様か不具合かミスか不明で、実際困るので何かおわかりになりましたら是非お教え下さい。

cameraでも同様でした。タグにcordovaを追記させて頂きます。

```js
function onDeviceReady(){
  console.log('start');

  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('timeout1');
    alert('timeout2');
    console.log('timeout3');
  }, 1000);

  navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles){
    console.log('success1');
    alert('success2');
    console.log('success3');
  }, function(){
    console.log('error1');
    alert('error2');
    console.log('error3');
  }, {limit: 1, duration: 120});
}
```

2015/05/01 12時追記

cordova-plugin-consoleなるプラグインがあることを知りました。試してみたいのですが
monacaをGOLDプランにしないとcordovaプラグインの追加ができないようで、現状試せません。

Comment: 純粋に alert('success') のところで処理がとまっていたから。。という事ではなくてですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。添付のalertをコメントアウトした状態ではログが出ず、コメントを外しalertを実行するとログが出ますので、ご指摘の反対の現象ではないかと思います。

Comment: なるほど。謎ですね。最初の console.log('start') は alert 関係なく表示されますか？

Comment: はい、startは常に出ています

Comment: アプリがアクティブじゃないと console.log が出ないみたいな制約があるのでしょうか。 alert を消した場合、 1,3 共に出力されませんか？

Comment: alertを消した場合1,3とも出力されません。

Comment: 本件に直接的に関係ないかもしれませんが、devicereadyの第三引数をなるべく省略しない方が良いと思います。ブラウザによって省略できないものも存在しますので。

Answer (score 0):

console.logにはフィルター機能があるので、それで出力されていない、ということではないでしょうか?

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` や `setTimeout()` で**実行タイミングを遅らせる事で成功している**ように読めます。
Cordovaのドキュメントに準じて、`onload` まで待ってみたらどうなりますか。

- [deviceready - Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ja/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html)

Re: TRNK さん